A Natural Transformation Property in Single-Sorted Categories
Background:
As a learning exercise, I am reproving some basic results in category theory within the single-sorted categories framework. Natural transformations in this framework have a slightly different definition: a function $\eta : \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{D}$ is a natural transformation between $F, G : \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{D}$ if

$\forall x \in \mathscr{C}$: $\text{dom}_\mathscr{D}(\eta(x)) = \text{dom}_\mathscr{D}(F(x))$, $\text{codom}_\mathscr{D}(\eta(x)) = \text{codom}_\mathscr{D}(G(x))$
$\forall x,y \in \mathscr{C}$: $\eta(y)\circ_\mathscr{D} F(x) = G(y)\circ_\mathscr{D}\eta(x)$

Notice that you get a component $\eta(x)$ each morphism $x$, not just a component for each object as is the case in the usual definition. The usual naturality square can be recreated in this framework as
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\text{dom}_\mathscr{D}(F(x)) @>{F(x)}>> \text{codom}_\mathscr{D}(F(x))\\
@V{\eta(\text{dom}_\mathscr{C}(x))}VV @VV{\eta(\text{codom}_\mathscr{C}(x))}V\\
\text{dom}_\mathscr{D}(G(x)) @>>{G(x)}> \text{codom}_\mathscr{D}(G(x))
\end{CD}
Question: My question is this. In the above square $\eta(x)$ corresponds to a diagonal arrow from $\text{dom}_\mathscr{D}(F(x))$ to $\text{codom}_\mathscr{D}(G(x))$. So if we were to put that arrow above, it would seem to suggest that
$$
G(x) \circ_\mathscr{D} \eta(\text{dom}_\mathscr{C}(x)) \stackrel{???}{=} \eta(x) 
$$ Is this actually provable? I can't seem to prove it from natural transformation and functor axioms for single-sorted categories. The main problem is that while we have axioms telling us what happens when we compose $\text{dom}_\mathscr{D}$ after $\eta(x)$, there are no axioms saying what happens for the opposite order of operations e.g. $\eta(\text{dom}_\mathscr{C}(x))$.

We use that for all composable $x,y \in \mathscr{C}$ we have $\eta(y)\circ_\mathscr{D} F(x) = G(y)\circ_\mathscr{D}\eta(x)$. Replacing $x$ by $\mathrm{dom}_\mathscr{C}(x)$ and $y$ by $x$, we then use that $F(\mathrm{dom}_\mathscr{C}(x))$ is an identity morphism.

I see. Since $F(\text{dom}\mathscr{C}(x)) = \text{dom}\mathscr{D}(\eta(x))$, $\eta(x) \circ_\mathscr{D} F(\text{dom}\mathscr{C}(x)) = \eta(x) \circ\mathscr{D} \text{dom}_\mathscr{D}(\eta(x))  = \eta(x)$.
